# Iterate through all the records in all the pages in a Angular.js Datatable ng-table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I have a ng-table (angular.js datable) implementation with 25 records per page, on the page i have a submit button on clicking which i need to iterate through all records in all the pages to find which records have been modified in this table.

below is my code with which i can only iterate through the records in the current selected page, not the rest of the pages.

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams(
                    {
                        page: 1,
                        count: 25,
                    },
                    {
                        total: records.length,
                        getData: function ($defer, params) {
                            $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(records, params.orderBy()) : result;
                            $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;
                            $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                            $defer.resolve($scope.data);
                        }
                    });


var skus = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.tableParams.data, function (product) {
                    if (product.quantity > 0) {
                        var sku =
                          {
                            AddToCart: true,
                            CategoryId: product.categoryId,
                            PriceCharged: product.displayPrice,
                            Quantity: product.quantity,
                            SkuCode: product.skuCode
                         }
                        skus.push(sku);
                    }        
                });
```

Comment: Those data are on server? Then I think you can really access only those 25 currently displayed. Because that's all what the client knows about. Or you will have to fire a request to server. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: yes the records are from a API service call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you could use event [ngTableEventsChannel.onDatasetChanged](http://ng-table.com/#/events/demo-subscribe) to catch modified row and copy it to a new object. 
You might also try to use ng-change on edited cell.

And remember that you have all your records in records object.